# In PHP/MySQL should I open multiple database connections or share 1?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I am wanting to hear what others think about this?  Currently, I make a mysql database connection inside of a header type file that is then included in the top of every page of my site.  I then can run as many queries as I want on that 1 open connection.  IF the page is built from 6 files included and there is 15 different mysql queries, then they all would run on this 1 connection.

Now sometimes I see classes that make multiple connections, like 1 for each query.

Is there any benefit of using one method over the other?  I think 1 connection is better then multiple but I could be wrong?

Comment: With many databases (e.g. postgresql) opening connections is expensive.  Auth has to be checked, buffers are allocated... it can run a good 30 milliseconds on my dev box sometimes, if not longer.  This is less true with mysql -- connections are faster.  But there's still going to be overhead, so connecting as infrequently as possible is desirable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Creating connections can be expensive (<s>I don't have a reference for this statement as yet</s> **Edit:** Aha! [Here it is](http://www.jpipes.com/index.php?/archives/99-MySQL-Connection-Management-in-PHP-How-Not-To-Do-Things.html)) so it seems as if the consensus is to use fewer connections. Using a single connection for all queries on a single page seems to be a better choice than multiple connections.

Comment: Not only should you be using a single connection per HTTP Request, you should consider using Persistent Connections in order to scale your application.  Both the mysqli and PDO interfaces in PHP support persistent connections.

Answer (score 6):

In PHP+MySQL usually there is no much sence to use multiple connections per page (just slower and a little more RAM consumed).

The only way it might be useful is when you alter connection paremters which might interfer with other pages (like collation). But good PHP programs usually never do that kind of stuff.

Also, it is a good idea to enable persistent connections, so that 1 MySQL connection would be reused across multiples page executions.

Comment: +1 for your first two points -- right on the money.  But as to the last point, persistent connections aren't all they're cracked up to be.  For one, any connection state gets carried over from script to script, which may have unintended consequences (temp tables that don't get cleaned up, dangling transactions, etc.).  Also, you end up with many of your precious database connections attached to idle apache threads, which is just a waste of resources.  Better to use a real connection pool, along the lines of SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 2):

If really depends on the level of activity you suspect the site will generate - if it's a high traffic web site, you'll soon run out of connections (unless you set the adjust MySQLs max connections to a stupidly high level, but that'll eventually grind the server to a halt).

I'd generally recommend that the front end of a web site should use a shared database object (`singleton is your friend`), as it doesn't require a great deal of discipline to write with this is mind and you won't waste time making connections. If you require additional concurrent queries on the backend, it shouldn't be that much of a deal as this isn't likely to be a highly trafficked area.

Answer (score 2):

Its not recommended to execute multiple small queries where the work can be done using just one query, you can use a single query to get data from multiple tables and ieven multiple databases. see the link below:

http://www.x-developer.com/php-scripts/sql-connecting-multiple-databases-in-a-single-query

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any benefit of using multiple connections, I 'd rather think it is a sign of bad structure. These are the reasons I can think of against using multiple connections:

- You have to initialize the database multiple times. Setting conection properties upon connection establishment (like [`SET NAMES UTF8`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html)) would have to be done on multiple line.
- It is definitely slower than a single connection.
- A non-technical reason: Someone working with your code will most probably not expect it and might spend hours debugging the connection properties he had set in another connection.

Having a global connection object (or a class providing one) is the much better approach in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the classes that make multiple connections aren't just returning a reference to the already open connection when one is open? I've seen a lot of stuff structured that way. It really is better performance-wise to use only one connection per page.