# database connections for social networking site

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I am creating a social networking site with php+mysql . currently i create a database connetion for my database in a function and i call it in the begining of every displayable page . I dont understand about how database connections works .
 
I read this link [In PHP/MySQL should I open multiple database connections or share 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077654/in-php-mysql-should-i-open-multiple-database-connections-or-share-1). i get something from this
but

1. how the database connection works when different users login?
2. Should i use different database connections for different purposes ?

Answer (score 2):

For each run of PHP (each time someone requests a .php page), you generally need one connection. You only need different connections if you want to query different databases in the same script.

Comment: thanks a lot . do i need different connections to solve any performance issues if site traffic increases ? if i dont need , then can i proceed with a single connection as i have only one database and go for caching solutions like memcache for avoiding performance degrade because of traffic