# Is it better to have 1 connection per query or separate connections for each?

Tags: php, mysqli

Is it better/secure to create a separate DB connection for each query (sample1) or should I just make one DB connection for both (sample2) ?

I have 2 queries to make to a database.

1. Select (to check if email exists in table).
2. Insert (if email does not exist create record in table).

I'm mainly interested in the security and resource cost of one method over the other.

NOTE: the sample code below is a simplified version of a user registration code.

Sample 1.

```
<?php
    $NEW_EMAIL="sample@gmail.com";

    $prep_sel = 'SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=?';
    $link1 = mysqli_stmt_init($dbc);

    if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($link1, $prep_sel)) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($link1, 's', $e);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($link1);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($link1);
    }

    // If record does not exist, then insert it.

    if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($link1) == 0) { // Available.
        $prep_ins= 'INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES (?)';
        $link2 = mysqli_stmt_init($dbc);

        if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($link2, $prep_ins)) {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($link2, 'sssss', $NEW_EMAIL);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($link2);
        }
    }
?>
```

Sample 2.

```
<?php
    $NEW_EMAIL="sample@gmail.com";

    $prep_sel = 'SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=?';
    $link1 = mysqli_stmt_init($dbc);

    if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($link1, $prep_sel)) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($link1, 's', $e);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($link1);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($link1);
    }

    // If record does not exist, then insert it.

    if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($link1) == 0) { // Available.
        $prep_ins= 'INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES (?)';

        if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($link1, $prep_ins)) {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($link1, 'sssss', $NEW_EMAIL);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($link1);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: For Performance ist better to only open one Connection.

Comment: Separate connection for each DB

Comment: Change your email field in your database to be UNIQUE and you can do a INSERT without using a select and filter the result error to show the proper message.

Comment: A better way to make the Connection more secure to only allow SELECT and INSERT Statements for the Database User

Comment: For security reason you better make separate connection with different database_user and access for `SELECT`

Comment: Also note that `mysqli_stmt_init` doesn't open a new DB connection, it just allocates an object to be used for a prepared statement.

Comment: @ColourDalnet, what do you mean? Why do think that two database users is more secure than only one user?

Comment: I know that there are so many protection to avoid sql injection. But I'm still didn't want to give access to `UPDATE` and `DELETE` in case I just need `SELECT` and `INSERT` or just need a `SELECT`. Especially for `users` table, you can make a new account if have `INSERT` access. Sometime we made a mistake.

Comment: @user3526609 I've updated the bottom of my answer in regards the multiple/single connection if you would want to read about...

Comment: @JCOC611 - So at what point in sample 1 is a DB open connection occurring? Is it opening once or more than once?

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. I hope others find these useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a sample 3 option? If you change your `email` column in your database to be `UNIQUE` that means no duplicated emails will be allowed. See below table sample:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id int auto_increment primary key, 
    email varchar(20) unique
);
```

And if you try to register a new account that already uses that given email you will be given an error 1062 (aka Duplicate entry error).

So instead of running both, a `SELECT` and a `INSERT` query based on that, you could simple run the `INSERT` query given your email column is `UNIQUE`:

```
<?php
// Your database info
$db_host = 'xxxx';
$db_user = 'xxxx';
$db_pass = 'xxxx';
$db_name = 'xxxx';

// hardcoded email for testing purposes
$test_email ="sample@gmail.com";

// SQL query
$sql = 'INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES (?)';

// connect to database
$con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if ($con->connect_error)
{
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Prepare the query to make sure it is good to go
if (!$result = $con->prepare($sql))
{
    die('Query failed: (' . $con->errno . ') ' . $con->error);
}

// bind and test if the parameters are valid
if (!$result->bind_param('s', $test_email))
{
    die('Binding parameters failed: (' . $result->errno . ') ' . $result->error);
}

// execute and see if it executed as expected.
if (!$result->execute())
{
    if ($result->errno === 1062)
    {
        die("Email already in use...");
    }
    else
    {
        die('Execute failed: (' . $result->errno . ') ' . $result->error);
    }
}
else
{
    echo "account created!!";
}
```

---

[In regards whether its better to have a single connection or multiple connections, this is a very good reading](http://www.joinfu.com/) but as a resume you could reference your self to [In PHP/MySQL should I open multiple database connections or share 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2077674/342740)